# Why does this code always generate latches?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module OB_Addr_Contr_B1(
    input                       clk,
    input                       rst_n,
    input  wire signed [3:0]    o_00,
    output  reg     [31:0]      OB_Data_00,
                          
                                
    output  wire    [7:0]       addr_write_0,
    output  wire                write_enable_0      
);
    reg     [3:0]   cnt_0;
    reg     [5:0]   Data_cnt_00;
    reg             rom_enable_0;
    always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)begin
        if(!rst_n)begin
            cnt_0 <= 0;
            Data_cnt_00 <= 0;
        end
        else if(cnt_0 == 8) begin
            cnt_0 <= 1 ;
            Data_cnt_00 <= Data_cnt_00 + 1;
        end
        else begin
            cnt_0 <= cnt_0 + 1;
        end      
    end
    
    always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)begin
        if(!rst_n)begin
            rom_enable_0 <= 0;
        end
        else if(cnt_0 == 7)
            rom_enable_0 <= 1;
        else
            rom_enable_0 <= 0;
    
    end

    always@(*)begin
        if(cnt_0 == 0)
            OB_Data_00 = 0;
        else if(cnt_0<=8)begin
            OB_Data_00[31 - ((cnt_0-1'b1)<<2) -: 4] = o_00;
        end
        else
            OB_Data_00 = OB_Data_00;
    end

endmodule
```

My `cnt_0` loops between 1~8, the `always@(*)` statement has covered all cases, but the hardware synthesized by Vivado will still generate "RTL_LATCH".

[image]

Changing "always@(*)" to "always@(posedge clk)" does generate registers instead of "RTL_LATCH", but this gives me problems with my waveforms because it delays the assignment by one clk, which makes me very distressed.

I uploaded 3 pictures.  The first one above is the circuit diagram synthesized by the code I provided.

The first one below is the waveform diagram corresponding to the circuit diagram, the waveform is what I want, and it is correct when cnt_0 is 8 The output is "0xffffffff".

The waveform diagram below is a wrong waveform diagram. It is the waveform generated by changing "always@(*)" to "always@(posedge clk)". The delay of one cycle leads to the error of the result（0xfffffff0）.

[image]
[image]

I changed "always@(*)" to "always@(posedge clk)" and it did generate the circuit without LATCH, but also caused the waveform result to go from correct to wrong.

```
always@(cnt_0)begin
        case(cnt_0)
            0: OB_Data_00 = 0;
            1: OB_Data_00[31:28] = o_00;
            2: OB_Data_00[27:24] = o_00;
            3: OB_Data_00[23:20] = o_00;
            4: OB_Data_00[19:16] = o_00;
            5: OB_Data_00[15:12] = o_00;
            6: OB_Data_00[11: 8] = o_00;
            7: OB_Data_00[ 7: 4] = o_00;
            8: OB_Data_00[ 3: 0] = o_00;
            default:OB_Data_00 = 0;
        endcase
    end
```

I modified the codes as suggested above and they still generate LATCH.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This line might be a cause for the inferred latch because it retains the state of `OB_Data_00`:

```
        OB_Data_00 = OB_Data_00;
```

You can probably simplify the `always` block as follows since `cout_0` can never be greater than 8:

```
always @(*) begin
    if (cnt_0 == 0)
        OB_Data_00 = 0;
    else
        OB_Data_00[31 - ((cnt_0-1'b1)<<2) -: 4] = o_00;
end
```

> the always@(*) statement has covered all cases

That statement is incorrect.  This line is also a potential cause of inferred latches because it does not make an assignment to all 32 bits of `OB_Data_00`:

```
        OB_Data_00[31 - ((cnt_0-1'b1)<<2) -: 4] = o_00;
```

For example, when cnt_0=2, it resolves to:

```
        OB_Data_00[27:24] = o_00;
```

This only assigns to 4 of the 32 bits of `OB_Data_00`, leaving the other 28 bits to retain their state.

The `case` version of your code infers latches for the same reason.  The `case` version has another problem: an incomplete sensitivity list.  It should use `always @*`

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood what you meant earlier, now I have modified the code